# How to create a drop down in grafana dashboard which is based on sysdig metrics label

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, metrics, sysdig

I am trying to create a drop down in grafana panel for the below metric :

cloud_storage_request_count{repo="github",method="create",region="ap-south",zone="ap-south-1"}

I want to create a dropdown based on labels region and zone in grafana dashboard like attached screenshot.
[Dropdown example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpvF4.png)

Please help. I am new to grafana and sysdig.

Answer (score 4):

To do that you need to go in your dashboard, then :

- *Settings > Variables > New*
- In the **General** block, you need to choose *Query* as the variable type.
- In the **Query Options** block, you need to chose your datasource in the dropdown
- Then, in the same block, you'll have a *Query* textfield. Here you have to use the grafana function called **label_values**

You can find the documentation for this function [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable).

So basically, for your use case, to retrieve the label value for the `region` label, you'll have something like this :

```
label_values(cloud_storage_request_count,region)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am now seeing drop down for Zone and Region, but values are not shown. I guess i need to emit new fresh metrics , i think 2 days old metric is getting not loaded by grafana due to some reason.

Comment: You have a preview at the bottom of the "Add variable" page in Grafana. It will refresh any time you click outside the *Query* textbox. Thus, you should be able to test your query (or another one) without going back to your dashboard.